# How to use AllNestedConditions in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I tried like below;

```
    public class MySwitch extends AllNestedConditions {

    public MySwitch(ConfigurationPhase configurationPhase) {
        super(configurationPhase);
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "EnableSomething")
    static class OnProperty {
    }
}
```

but i get error like:
`Failed to Instantiate as no default Constructor Found`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the super-constructor to tell spring in which phase the condition should be considered. In your case it should look like this:

```
public class MySwitch extends AllNestedConditions {

    public MySwitch() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN);
    }

    @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "EnableSomething")
    static class OnProperty {
    }
}
```